# Spring Boot tests for remote server

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using jUnit and SpringBootTest for my application. e.g.:

```
mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/categories")...
```

Is that possible to run tests on a remote server? e.g.

```
mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("192.168.1.1:80/categories")...
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, as it's beyond a unit test or an integration test.
If you're testing an existing webservice, it's not a mock anymore. For getting data from an external webservice, you can use the RestTemplate class:

```
public class Application {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

public static void main(String args[]) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Quote quote = restTemplate.getForObject("http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", Quote.class);
    log.info(quote.toString());
}}
```

(Example taken from [Spring docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/))

Answer (score 0):

*Spring MVC Test Framework* is meant to test *Spring MVC* controllers **without** actually starting up *HTTP* server.

In your case, in your *JUnit* tests you should use real *HTTP* client (like `RestTemplate`) or to keep things even simpler go with [**Rest Assured**](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured) library that was designed for that.

Sample Rest Assured based test:

```
given().
    param("key1", "value1").
    param("key2", "value2").
when().
    post("/somewhere").
then().
    body(containsString("OK"));
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i'll use here.

Comment: If that answers your question you can mark answer as correct or upvote it.